# Is it possible to do this in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 3 tables

- Project
- Parts
- intermediate `Part_and_Project`

A `Project` has several codes of `Parts`

For example:

```
Id_Project: 1
   Id_Part:PART-098-876

Id_Project:1
   Id_Part:PART-055-777
```

In `Parts` there are several codes change dates, but the codes can repeat

How can I select the highest `Parts` codes, take MAX value in `Date_Initial`, `Date_Expected`, `Date_Finish`?

How can I have as a result  like this?

```
1,PART-098-876,2018-05-14 00:00:00 PM,2018-05-03 00:00:00 PM,2018-05-03 00:00:00 PM 
1,PART-055-777,2018-05-14 00:00:00 PM,2018-05-03 00:00:00 PM,2018-05-09 00:00:00 PM
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    Project.Id_Project, Id_Part, 
    MAX(Date_Initial),
    MAX(Date_Expected),
    MAX(Date_Finish) 
FROM 
    Project
LEFT JOIN 
    Part_and_Project ON Part_and_Project.Id_Project = Project.Id_Project
INNER JOIN 
    Parts ON Parts.Id_Part = Part_and_Project.Id_Part
```

but it does not work

Data for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parts]
(
    [Id_Part] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Date_Initial] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Expected] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Finish] [datetime] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project]
(
    [Id_Project] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Id_User] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Value_Revenue] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Launch] [varchar](20) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Proyect] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_Project] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Part_and_Project]
(
    [Id_Project] [int] NULL,
    [Id_Part] [varchar](30) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [Parts] ([Id_Part], [Date_Initial], [Date_Expected],[Date_Finish], [Name]) 
VALUES ('PART-098-876', '2018-06-12 00:00:00 PM', '2017-05-03 00:00:00 PM', '2011-05-04 00:00:00 PM'),
       ('PART-098-876', '2014-06-03 00:00:00 PM', '2013-05-03 00:00:00 PM', '2014-09-08 00:00:00 PM'),
       ('PART-098-876', '2015-06-17 00:00:00 PM', '2013-03-02 00:00:00 PM', '2013-07-03 00:00:00 PM'),
       ('PART-098-876', '2018-05-14 00:00:00 PM', '2018-05-03 00:00:00 PM', '2018-05-09 00:00:00 PM'),
       ('PART-055-777', '2013-03-13 00:00:00 PM', '2017-05-03 00:00:00 PM', '2011-07-08 00:00:00 PM'),
       ('PART-055-777', '2011-03-07 00:00:00 PM', '2013-05-03 00:00:00 PM', '2013-07-08 00:00:00 PM'),
       ('PART-055-777', '2015-06-17 00:00:00 PM', '2013-03-02 00:00:00 PM', '2015-08-07 00:00:00 PM'),
       ('PART-055-777', '2018-05-14 00:00:00 PM', '2018-05-03 00:00:00 PM', '2018-05-09 00:00:00 PM')

INSERT INTO [Part_and_Proyect] ([Id_Project], [Id_Part]) 
VALUES ('1', 'PART-098-876'), ('1', 'PART-055-777')
```

Comment: What effort have you made to solve this problem yourself? I don't see a single `SELECT` statement in what you've posted.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm Sorry ,I fixed

Comment: One small Tip,please don't paste in Bold

Comment: You can use CTRL+K to format code and space and enter as well for formattting

Comment: @TheGameiswar I'll do it from now on Thanks

Comment: Is [ID_Part]  unique in the [Part_and_Proyect] table? If not, is a combination of [ID_Project] and [ID_Part] unique in the [Part_and_Proyect] table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT  Proyect.Id_Project,
        Id_Part,
        Date_Initial,
        Date_Expected,
        Date_Finish 
    FROM Proyect
    LEFT JOIN Part_and_Proyect 
        ON Part_and_Proyect.Id_Project = Proyect.Id_Project
    INNER JOIN Parts 
        ON Parts.Id_Part = Part_and_Proyect.Id_Part 
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT MAX(Date_Initial) AS Max_Date_Initial FROM Parts p 
        WHERE p.Id_Part = Parts.Id_Part) as di
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT MAX(Date_Expected) AS Max_Date_Expected FROM Parts p 
        WHERE p.Id_Part = Parts.Id_Part) as de
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT MAX(Date_Finish) AS Max_Date_Finish FROM Parts p 
        WHERE p.Id_Part = Parts.Id_Part) as df
    WHERE   di.Max_Date_Initial = Date_Initial 
        AND de.Max_Date_Expected = Date_Expected 
        AND df.Max_Date_Finish = Date_Finish
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on how the [Part_And_Proyect] table is set up. If each part exists in only one Project and is not duplicated within a Project in the [Part_And_Proyect] table then this works OK, and will work for any number of Parts in the [Part_And_Proyect] table.

The code creates a LOOP which works down the ID_Part values in the [Part_And_Proyect] table using a variable (@ID_Part). First, it inserts the ID_Project and ID_Part values into the temporary table (#Maxdates), then it inserts each of the required Max Dates for that part. After that, it increases the @ID_Part variable to the next ID_Part value and repeats the process.

```
CREATE TABLE #Maxdates
(
[Id_Project] INT,
[Id_Part] VARCHAR(30),
[MAX_Date_Initial] DATETIME,
[MAX_Date_Expected] DATETIME,
[MAX_Date_Finish] DATETIME
)
GO

DECLARE @Id_Part NCHAR(12) = (SELECT MIN(Id_Part) FROM [Part_And_Proyect])
WHILE @Id_Part <= (SELECT MAX(Id_Part) FROM [Part_And_Proyect])
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Maxdates VALUES
(
(SELECT ID_Project FROM [Part_And_Proyect] WHERE ID_Part = @ID_Part)
,
@ID_Part
,
(SELECT MAX([Date_Initial]) FROM PARTS WHERE ID_Part = @ID_Part)
,
(SELECT MAX([Date_Expected]) FROM PARTS WHERE ID_Part = @ID_Part)
,
(SELECT MAX([Date_Finish]) FROM PARTS WHERE ID_Part = @ID_Part)
)
SET @ID_Part =  (SELECT MIN(ID_Part) FROM [Part_And_Proyect] WHERE ID_Part > @ID_Part)
END
GO

SELECT * FROM #Maxdates
```